# Can I use an aggregate function over a specific index?

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have data as follows:

```
  Month   User        Visits
April   101078350   16
April   101187789   10000
April   101204204   98
April   101220432   659
April   103021861   25
April   103052403   93
April   103235453   25
April   103309704   77
April   103613303   87
April   103641403   735
April   103698304   62
April   103709630   198
April   103880860   94
April   104090303   448
May      104146303  561
May      104170303  143
May     104216403   273
May     104531678   786
May     104548151   811
May     104584503   15000
```

Here, Month and User form a multindex.  Is there a an easy way to take the mean of each month granted that the month is part of an index? As of now, I reset the index, re group by the month, and calculate the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [16]: df.groupby(level='Month').mean()
Out[16]:
            Visits
Month
April   901.214286
May    2929.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` with aggreagting `mean`:

```
print (df.groupby(level='Month')['Visits'].mean().to_frame())
            Visits
Month             
April   901.214286
May    2929.000000
```

Or [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
print (df.mean(level='Month'))
            Visits
Month             
April   901.214286
May    2929.000000
```

Timings are same (`3ms` is small diff):

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000)

In [379]: %timeit (df.groupby(level='Month')['Visits'].mean().to_frame())
10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop

In [380]: %timeit (df.mean(level='Month'))
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  Do something like

```
df.mean(level = 0)
```